# Change laravel project name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to change my Laravel 8 project but I run into an issue when I use this command: `php artisan app:name new_name`

The error is:

> There are no commands defined in the "app" namespace.

I went through some solutions proposed in Stack Overflow, Github and other forums, but nothing seems to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `php artisan list` to see all the commands available

There is none `app:name`

To change the name of your project edit your .env and modify `APP_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

1. go to .env file
2. open .env file in any code editor
3. find at APP-NAME = "" in .env file
4. edit APP-NAME = "Your Project Name"
5. put your desired name in "" (double quotes)
6. save .env file
7. restart your server

I think it will be work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
// go to .env file    change your app name example below
```

> APP_NAME=type your project name here

Answer (score 0):

Got to .env file at the root of you project and update `APP_NAME="Your app name"`

Also `php artisan app:name new_name` doesn't exist. You can do `php artisan list` to see all available artisan commands.